# Blackberry - Is this a guaranteed approach for detecting a valid connection type?

Tags: web-services, http, blackberry, wap, httpconnection

I've created following two methods for reliably building a connection for making a data connection. So far I haven't had any issues testing this approach with users.

I'd love to get some community feedback about this approach and letting me know if anything seems in buildConnectionString(). Please see code below:

```
private static String buildConnectionString()
{

    //The Device is a simultaor --> TCP
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator())
        return ";deviceside=true;ConnectionTimeout=20000";

    String st = "";

    //A carrier is providing us with the data service
    if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_CARRIER) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_CARRIER)
    {

        // blackberry internet service
        ServiceRecord rec = getBIBSRecord();//Apply for BIS access to get info about BIS recordset
        if (rec != null)//couldn't find the right record
            st = "[THIS CONNECTION STRING IS REMOVED, PLEASE APPLY FOR BIS ACCESS TO GET THIS STRING]";
        else if(GetWap2().length() > 0)
            st = GetWap2();
        else
            st = ";deviceside=true";// let the phone try to do the work

    }
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS)
        st = ";deviceside=false";// use the clients blackberry enterprise server
    else
        st = ";deviceside=true";// let the phone do the work if it can

    return st + ";ConnectionTimeout=45000";
}

public static String GetWap2() {
    String wap2Postfix = null;
    final ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
    final ServiceRecord[] records = sb.findRecordsByCid("WPTCP");

    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
        // Search through all service records to find the valid non Wi-Fi
        // WAP 2.0 Gateway Service Record.
        if (records[i].isValid() && !records[i].isDisabled()
                && records[i].getUid() != null
                && records[i].getUid().length() != 0
                && records[i].getUid().toLowerCase().indexOf("wifi") == -1
                && records[i].getUid().toLowerCase().indexOf("mms") == -1) {
            wap2Postfix = ";ConnectionUID=" + records[i].getUid();
            break;
        }//endif
    }//end for
    return wap2Postfix;
}// end wap postfix
```

Possible questions to consider:

- If a BIS string exists (recordset found), will it always work (aside from being blocked by a corporate network)?
- If a WAP2 string exists (recordset found), will it always work (aside from being blocked by a corporate network)?
- Should I check for MDS support first as opposed to carrier support?
- Beyond extreme cases where carriers block a connection,  will the above approach work?

Let me me know!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=884